# Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'Boolean Type'

Tags: swift, boolean

This question has been asked a bunch of times, and I have looked at so many answers, but I can't get the answer because a) They asked it a long time ago and the code does not work anymore(updated) or b) It is not suited to my case.

Here's the code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {     

//SET INITIAL CONTROLLER
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController: UIViewController
    if() //your condition if user is already logged in or not
    {
       // if already logged in then redirect to MainViewController

        initialViewController =     mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainController") as! MainViewController // 'MainController' is the storyboard id of MainViewController 
    }
    else
    {
       //If not logged in then show LoginViewController
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as! LoginViewController // 'LoginController' is the storyboard id of      LoginViewController 

    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 return true
```

}

This is the code from the following thread : [Show another view controller at the first launch and not again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005900/show-another-view-controller-at-the-first-launch-and-not-again)

I am trying to use this, but the error comes on the line of "if()". Has there been an update that gets rid of that? or was I just putting in wrong code?. It's in the right place (AppDelegate.swift).

If you need any more references or information, just comment below

Thank you in advance!

P.S: I would have just commented on his answer, but I don't have 50 points

Comment: The statement `if()` means that you need to replace the parentheses with a conditional statement like: `if a == b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `if` statement is not evaluating anything, that's why you're receiving that error. The code below is assuming you're saving the user's status in `NSUserDefaults` (`userKey`)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {     

//SET INITIAL CONTROLLER
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController: UIViewController

   //retrive the user key or status from NSUserDefaults here
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let userKey = defaults.stringForKey("userKey"){
       // if already logged in then redirect to MainViewController

        initialViewController =     mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainController") as! MainViewController // 'MainController' is the storyboard id of MainViewController 
    }
    else
    {
       //If not logged in then show LoginViewController
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as! LoginViewController // 'LoginController' is the storyboard id of      LoginViewController 

    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 return true
}
```

Comment: There's an error saying "Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'"...Other than that, everything is getting better.

Comment: The erro shows up on a closed bracket. The bracket that ends **func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {**

Comment: Im not too sure whats wrong there, I just tested the code above with no errors

Comment: Spoke too soon, so the code is correct and everything is in place. But, it is not working. I ran the app, then deleted it from the running background, then started it again, and it brings me back to the first view controller. I think it has something to do with "UserKey" it's the statement where it says **if let userKey = defaults.stringForKey("userKey")**

Comment: Thats because you haven't stored anything yet for `userKey` within `NSUserDefaults` you should be storing that when the user logs in the `LoginViewController`

Comment: does that mean using [let userKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()]

Comment: I don't think so, look into saving and reading 'NSUserDefaults'